# Eclipse - Find and Replace functionality suddenly disable in Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, m2eclipse

I am getting a wonderful problem.

I works on remote Linux machine through VNC Viewer. 
In eclipse, the find and Replace(Ctrl + f) functionality sometimes disables suddenly in the middle of work.
Even not only that some other functionalists also, but majorly stopping my work is disable of "Ctrl + f"

do you have any idea to re enable that.

I tried:

1. Changed prospective
2. Restart eclipse solved, but i don't like that solution, because my applications will run from eclipse, so every time i have to re-run again,

Comment: What do you mean by "disabled"? Does the the key combination stop working?

Comment: Which brand/version of VNC Viewer are you using? There was some issue with CTRL before (http://sourceforge.net/p/tigervnc/bug-tracker/79/)